# How can I execute a function cleanly off of the return status of two other functions' success?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have one function which relies on the successful return statuses of two other functions. I.e. if either function is a failure, the third function needs to update something within itself to reflect this, but still proceed.  Is there a clean way to execute this third function, without being redundant?

In my case, I have the following, where `func1` and `func2` are returning either success or failure:

```
bool status;
bool status2;
status = func1();
status2 = func2();
if (status && status2){
 func3(other_args,true)
else func3(other_args, false);
```

And I feel like this is not done well at all.  My `func3` conducts a write of a plethora of information and relies on knowing if either operations that were conducted failed.  Is there a cleaner way to implement this third function call?

My first thoughts were:

```
if (func1 && func2){
    func3(some_other_args, true)
else func3(some_other_args, false)
```

Is this the right mindset, or is there something much cleaner here?

Comment: Isn't that just the same as `func3(some_other_args, status && status2)`?

Comment: While this question can only lead to opinion-based answers, my thought in these cases is to always use whatever is the most human-readable.  Without doubt, you will one day have to come back and maintain this code (or, somebody else will).  The compiler will make whatever optimizations it wants whether you write it as the top set of code, or the bottom set, or as in other comments to your question.  Therefore, there isn't likely a technical reason for one over the other.  Maintainability should be the primary concern here.

Comment: Assuming that in the second example you intend to actually call f1 and f2, I should warn you that if f1 fails then f2 will not get called, while your first version of the code will call both functions. This may be important! Using & instead of && will fix this bug, but as @molbdnilo says, that is prone to "fixing".

Comment: func3(soa, func1() * func(2))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the condition as the parameter to avoid branching.

```
status = func1();
status2 = func2();
func3(other_args, (status && status2))
```

Comment: Yep, or even more concise: `func3(other_args, func1() && func2())`

Comment: @Magix That's not equivalent - func2() might not be called.

Answer (score 3):

Since you really want both results, then *if* the order of execution isn't important to you, the shortest you can get is to not short-circuit:

```
func3(other_args, func1() & func2());
```

but this is susceptible to the mistaken bug fix ("verschlimmbessern" in German), when you return to the code after a few weeks and "correct" the conjunction.

The more robust solution is

```
auto status = func1();
auto status2 = func2();
func3(other_args, status && status2);
```

Comment: I'd still put a comment there that `func2` must be called regardless of `status1`.

Comment: Another option might be to use * rather than &, as it is less likely to get "fixed" into &&

Answer (score 0):

Maybe other C++ ways: Pass `func1()` and `func2()` themselves into `func3()` which also takes care of the function return statuses like so:

```
void func3(other_args i, decltype(func1) f1, decltype(func2) f2){
    if (f1() && f2()) { 
        //do true 
    }
    else {
        //do false
    }   
}
```

This way `func3()` call becomes more cleaner :

```
func3(other_args, func1, func2);
```

Answer (score -2):

In your case you can just write:

```
auto status = func1();
auto status2 = func2();
func3(other_args, status && status2);
```

Or maybe I don't quite understand your question

Comment: func1 and func2 still need the parenthesis: `func1() && func2()`